# AdaBoost, how to understand the "weighted class probability estimates" in SAMME.R

Tags: classification, multi-class, adaboost

[SAMME.R](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/samme.pdf) is a multi-class classifier of AdaBoost. And I am confused about the **weighted class probability estimates** in SAMME.R. Here is the algorithm:

> (1) Initialalize the observation weights $w_i=\frac{1}{n},i=1,2,...,n$
>
> (2) For $m=1$ to $M$:
>
> (a) Fit a classifer $T^{(m)}(x)$ to the training data using weights $w_i$.
>
> (b) Obtain the weighted class probability estimates
>
> \begin{equation}p^{(m)}_k(x)=Prob_w(c=k|x),k=1,2,...,K\end{equation}
>
> (c) Set
>
> \begin{equation}
> h^{(m)}_k(x) =(K-1)(\log{p^{(m)}_k(x)}-\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k'}^{}\log{p^{(m)}_{k'}(x)}),k=1,2,...,K.
> \end{equation}
>
> (d) Set
>
> \begin{equation}w_i=w_i * exp(-\frac{K-1}{K}y^T_i\log{p^{(m)}(x_i)}),i=1,2,...,m.\end{equation}
>
> (e) Re-normalize $w_i$
>
> (3) Output
>
> \begin{equation}C(x)=\arg\max_k{\sum_{m=1}^{M}h^{(m)}_k(x)}\end{equation}

How can I understand the **weighted class probability estimates** in (2)(b) of SAMME.R and how do I get the $p^{(m)}_k(x)$?

Comment: This is a question about the algorithm, not about Python code. This should be considered on topic here, IMO.

Comment: @gung, what is IMO?

Comment: [IMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acronyms:_I#IMO)

Comment: @gung, sorry, I am not a native English speaker. But does the question on this site must be about Python code?

Comment: No need to apologize. On this site, questions about Python code are off topic. Someone voted to close your question. My comment was for other potential close voters. Your question is perfectly fine for this site.